# Live.com OAuth revoke access

Tags: oauth, live

What is the url or request for revoking access token in live.com OAuth?
The similar request on Google Oauth is:

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=%access_or_refresh_token%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff752110.aspx, it appears that revoking consent is a manual process and even then, it does not immediately revoke a token.